# Python3.4 Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a `multiprocessing pool` to access multiple urls and pull data with a specific function simultaneously.  Unfortunately I keep getting duplicate output for `eachticker` in the `ticker_list`.  I want a single line of output for `eachTicker`

## code

```
ticker_list = []

with open('/home/a73nk-xce/Documents/Python/SharkFin/SP500_Fin/SP_StockChar/ticker.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for rows in spamreader:
        pass

    for eachTicker in rows:
        ticker_list.append(eachTicker)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(20)
    pool.map(IncData, ticker_list)
    pool.terminate()
```

## OUTPUT

```
[28105000, 16863000, 11242000, 0, 8355000, 87000, 0, 0, 2800000, -15000, 2785000, 395000, 2390000, 864000, 0, 1509000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1526000, 0, 1526000]
[1262006, 829648, 432358, 0, 252384, 0, 0, 0, 179974, -2082, 177892, 11392, 166500, 45959, 0, 120541, -2171, 0, 0, 0, 118370, 0, 118370]
[6981000, 3388000, 3593000, 719000, 2043000, 0, 0, 0, 831000, -72000, 759000, 113000, 646000, 142000, 0, 504000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 504000, 0, 504000]
[6981000, 3388000, 3593000, 719000, 2043000, 0, 0, 0, 831000, -72000, 759000, 113000, 646000, 142000, 0, 504000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 504000, 0, 504000]
[69269000, 0, 69269000, 0, 55852000, 20058000, 6666000, 0, 13794000, 570000, 28054000, 13690000, 14364000, 686400
```

As you can see the output ablove as duplicates in it and it does that while running the entire program

Comment: could you be a bit more precise? What does IncData do? In the example you don't collect the results, how do you do that?

Comment: IncData is a program I wrote to access web url's with `requests.get` that pulls and formats data and into a csv file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem correctly as the provided information are incomplete.

If `IncData` is writing its results on a single file, then the issue is due to the concurrent access of the worker processes to that file. If a file is written by more than one process at the same time, the writes will overlap resulting in the corruption of the file. This might be the reason for what you call "duplicated lines".

The best approach would be letting the `IncData` callable return the result output to the parent process instead of writing itself on the file. The parent process would then aggregate the results from the workers and write them sequentially on a file.

Something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(20) as pool:
        results_list = pool.map(IncData, ticker_list)

    with open('/path/to/your/file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        csvfile.writelines(results_list)
```

Comment: take a look at the edits above and you can see what the output looks like